# Setting up openCL SDKs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, opencl, settings, variable-assignment

I have a task on uni starts with setting the visual studio environment to :
OpenCL SDKs:

- AMD – AMD APP (Accelerated Parallel Processing)
- NVIDIA – CUDA (Compute Unified Device Architecture)
- Intel – Intel SDK for OpenCL Applications

OpenCL uses an “Installable Client Driver” (ICD), model

- To allow platforms from different vendors to co-exist
- Applications can choose a platform at runtime

And I don't know how to do it .. 
i need halp and thanks

I checked by running Regedit for the settings but I only found the default

Answer (score 0):

In order to make OpenCL available for pre-compiled programs you simply need to install the Nvidia, AMD or Intel GPU drivers, depending on which GPU you have (not that older Intel integrated GPUs don't support OpenCL).

For CPU OpenCL support you can install the [Intel runtime](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers) (Intel only) or [POCL](http://portablecl.org/) (open source, all modern CPUs supported, but you need to compile it from source). Unfortunately AMD does not provide APP SDK with CPU support anymore (although a simple web search will still get you the executables).

All of the above automatically register the respective ICD, so you don't have to do anything special about it.

For developing OpenCL applications you need a standalone [OpenCL ICD loader](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-ICD-Loader) (`.lib`/`.a` and `.dll`) and the [OpenCL headers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Headers) (`.h`), which you can get from those links, though you need to compile the former. These are also provided in ready to use, binary form in OpenCL SDKs such as the ones provided by [Intel](https://software.seek.intel.com/intel-opencl?os=windows) (which includes Intel's OpenCL CPU runtime) or [AMD](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/OCL-SDK/releases).